# Get model metadata in controller ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have model class as below:

```
public class student
{
public int id{ get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
pubblic string studentname{ get; set; }
[StringLength(50)]
public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

and controller

```
public class StudentController: ControllerBase
{
public class getColumns()
{
 //return list of student model and it's properties here
}
}
```

How to get list of model metadata in my controller?
Please advise!

Comment: `object[] attributes = typeof(student).GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(true));` - What are you trying to achieve? I highly doubt this is what will help you.

Comment: I am currently working angular and asp.net core api project.  what i want to achieve is to get model field and it's attribute and pass to angular to generate auto form.